# Launching .net app on startup on linux

Tags: linux, mono, debian, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I can't seem to find what the "proper" way to launch an app startup is on linux, i need to launch a mono app on startup on my raspberries (whenever the system is done loading, whatever that might mean in linux, and NOT on user logon, no one will be actively logging to the system).

What would be the correct way to tell raspbian (the linux distribution i'm using) "please launch my program whenever you're done loading whatever system level things you have to be done with"?

I need something that works 100% of the time and doesn't feel hacky (something like Windows services for example) and i'm completely new to linux. The only thing i had found when looking a while back asked you to provide a priority level and would fail depending on the level provided, i don't want to handle that, i want to register my program as something that should get launched after every startup and let the system handle the how / why etc.

Something that requires root or would run my program as root is a non issue and perfectly acceptable (completely disconnected devices, so if running as root gives an easier solution do not hesitate to go with that)

Comment: You should create an `Init Script` for your program. If `raspbian` is based on `Debian` this page should help you. [LSBInitScripts](https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts). To sum up: you must use the `$all virtual facility name` such that the script will be executed at the end (it is explained on that page)